# @ngrx Action called Infinitely with Effects

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Please forgive me if this is an easy answer. I have a complicated login logic that requires a few calls before a user has a complete profile. If a step fails, it shouldn't break the app -- the user just doesn't get some supplemental information.

The flow I'm looking to achieve is this:

1. Call `Revalidate`.
2. `Revalidate` calls `RevalidateSuccess` as well as `ProfileGet` (supplemental fetch to enhance the user's state).
3. `ProfileGetSuccess`.

To save tons of code, the actions exist (it's a giant file).

The app kicks off the action: `this._store.dispatch(new Revalidate())`

From there, we have the following effects:

```
@Effect()
public Revalidate: Observable<any> = this._actions.pipe(
  ofType(AuthActionTypes.REVALIDATE),
  map((action: Revalidate) => action),
  // This promise sets 'this._profile.currentProfile' (an Observable)
  flatMap(() => Observable.fromPromise(this._auth.revalidate())),
  // Settings are retrieved as a promise
  flatMap(() => Observable.fromPromise(this._settings.get())),
  switchMap(settings => 
    // Using map to get the current instance of `this._profile.currentProfile`
    this._profile.currentProfile.map(profile => {
      const onboarded = _.attempt(() => settings[SettingsKeys.Tutorials.Onboarded], false);
      return new RevalidateSuccess({ profile: profile, onboarded: onboarded });
  }))
);

//Since I couldn't get it working using concatMap, trying NOT to call two actions at once
@Effect()
public RevalidateSuccess: Observable<any> = this._actions.pipe(
  ofType(AuthActionTypes.REVALIDATE_SUCCESS),
  mapTo(new ProfileGet)
);

@Effect()
public ProfileGet: Observable<any> = this._actions.pipe(
  ofType(AuthActionTypes.PROFILE_GET),
  // We need to retrieve an auth key from storage
  flatMap(() => Observable.fromPromise(this._auth.getAuthorizationToken(Environment.ApiKey))),
  // Now call the service that gets the addt. user data.
  flatMap(key => this._profile.getCurrentProfile(`${Environment.Endpoints.Users}`, key)),
  // Send it to the success action.
  map(profile => {
  console.log(profile);
  return new ProfileGetSuccess({});
  })
);
```

Reducer:

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: Actions): State 
{
  switch (action.type) {
    case AuthActionTypes.REVALIDATE_SUCCESS:
      console.log('REVALIDATE_SUCCESS');
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        profile: action.payload.profile,
        onboarded: action.payload.onboarded
      };
    case AuthActionTypes.PROFILE_GET_SUCCESS:
      console.log('PROFILE_GET_SUCCESS');
      return { ...state, profile: action.payload.profile };
    case AuthActionTypes.INVALIDATE_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, isAuthenticated: false, profile: undefined };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

As the title mentions, dispatching the action runs infinitely. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies here:

`this._profile.currentProfile.map` needed to be `this._profile.currentProfile.take(1).map`. The issue wasn't the fact that all my actions were being called, but because I was running an action on an observable, I suppose it was re-running the action every time someone was touching the observable, which happened to be infinite times.

Moreso, I was able to refactor my action store so that I can get rid of my other actions to call to get the rest of the user's data, instead subscribing to `this._profile.currentProfile` and calling a non-effect based action, `ProfileSet`, when the observable's value changed. This let me remove 6 actions (since they were async calls and needed success/fail companion actions) so it was a pretty big win.